# XAMPP, MAMP, MySQL errors

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, mamp, macos-sierra

I'm facing a lot of errors at the moment ranging from "No such file or directory" to "Error 403 - Access to the requested directory is only available from the local network." along with a series of permission obstacles relating to mysql.

Admittedly I was playing around with mysql, XAMPP and MAMP today (I'm new to back-end programming) and think I've screwed something up somewhere that's preventing them from working correctly.

Specifically, I'm using XAMPP now and while the status is fine (green) and connected to my IP address, along with MySQL, Apache and ProFTPD services all being connected, I can't find any of the related XAMPP files needed to resolve Error 403. Eg.

```
Bryans-MacBook-Pro:~ bryanjordan$ chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var
chmod: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var: No such file or directory
```

When I open XAMPP, right-click and all in the `Applications` directory, all I see is a `Contents` folder with no reference to `xamppfiles`.

[image]

To clarify, I downloaded XAMPP, imported into `Applications`, opened, connected to servers and once re-directed in my browser, clicked `phpMyAdmin` but reached the 403 Error.

I've also linked MAMP and don't have this issue. I can access `phpMyAdmin` fine through this process.

I should also note, that even though I have MAMP operating fine, I can't access `mysql` via the command line even when I use the path directory instead of a simple, `mysql -u root -p` call. Instead I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I'm unsure if this is related but before downloading MAMP or XAMPP I was able to type "localhost/~bryanjordan" into the browser and I'd be redirected to my `Sites` directory. When I type the same URL in now, I receive this error:

```
The requested URL /~bryanjordan/ was not found on this server.
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up xampp or mamp should be simple to setup. Here is a link to a handy tutorial: https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-install-start-test-xampp-on-mac-osx.cfm

For XAMPP if it cannot find the folder make sure its actually in your applications folder and make sure your system has permissions to read and write to it.

For MAMP or even XAMPP, if you cannot start your mysql it might be permissions. Please see the link above for the relevant command to run on the command line.

Also given the amount of errors you are having i would recommend removing both and starting from scratch with just one of them using my link above.

Hope this helps!